# data driven report --send max 2 report when records return instead of sending every 10 min

Tags: ssrs

I have a data-driven report that is scheduled to run every 10 minutes; it sends the report if any records return.

I'd like to change this so the report is sent out at most twice a day.

For example: Currently, let's say the report generates records on the following runs for a given day:

- 02:10
- 08:40
- 12:20
- 14:40
- 16:30
- 21:50

As things stand now, each of those 6 runs will send the report out. If the process I want was in place, it would have sent the 02:10 and the 08:40 reports, and not sent the other 4 (even though records were generated), because it had already sent out 2 reports this day.

The count would restart at 0 reports sent out at midnight every day.

Comment: Sorry - it's not at all clear what you mean by "limit max 2 report" - a report listing just the top 2 records, instead of all records? the report is captured every 10 minutes, but only the two reports with the biggest values are sent?

Comment: Report runs every 10 min and if it returns any record then it will send report at every 10 min per schedule. instead of sending similar report every 10 min, I would like to send similar report max two times only. e.g report runs at 00:10 and it returns record so report will be sent on 00:10, 00:20, 00:30, 00:40... but I would like to limit for only two report(00:10, 00:20)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried rewording your question to (I hope) make it much clearer. Please feel free to roll back my edit if it doesn't represent what you want, or modify it if better but still not quite correct. You might want to comment here if it is correct, to let others know you approve of the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table

```
CREATE TABLE ReportRuns 
( RunDate Date, RunCounter Int)
```

The RunDate will contain the Date Portion only.

Everytime you run the report and there is data returning, you Update/Insert into this Table and increment the counter. If counter is already at 2, do nothing and don't send the report. if a record for the current day doesn't exist or does exist and the counter is 1, then update the counter to 2 and send the report. 
Next time it runs, the counter will be at 2 and the report won't be sent.

HTH.